# Logitech MX Anywhere 2 needs to re-pair after reboot (Linux)

Tags: linux, mouse, bluetooth, logitech-mouse

I recently bought a new laptop with a RTL8822CE Bluetooth controller (USB ID 13d3:3548).

I have paired most of my Bluetooth devices without any issue, except for my Anywhere MX 2.
Its behavior is really weird.

After a successful pairing and a reboot, when I try to connect again, it tries to connect multiple times per seconds for a few seconds then stops. It's like the mouse immediately breaks the connection after it connected.

Unpairing then re-pairing is not working from this point. I need to use a VM to make it work again:

1. In Linux, unpair the mouse,
2. Start a VM with Win10 (it does not work with Win7),
3. Link the bluetooth USB controller to the VM so I can pair the mouse in Win10,
4. Unpair then re-pair the mouse in Win10,
5. Close the VM,
6. Pair the Mouse in Linux.

The mouse will stay paired and connected as long as I don't reboot the laptop. I need to do this every time I reboot.

I couldn't find any help that solved this specific issue.
I tried a lot of things already (different modules, different software, different kernel...).

Any idea what could be happening and/or what to check ?

Thank you !

Comment: Didn't it come with its own BT dongle? I've computers here with built-in BT, but the Logitechs definitely work best with their own dongles.

Comment: Yes, I do have a Unifying dongle, but I don't have many USB ports on the laptop so I would rather use BT when I'm out. I use the dongle at home on my USB hub.

I can live with what I have now, but it's just annoying to set it up every day...

Comment: @xurei The BT Unifying dongle would likely eliminate the issue _(a USB hub would eliminate the lack of ports issue)_. Any chance you're accidentally changing the BT slot selected on the MX2 _(it has three BT pair slots - 1, 2, & 3)_? If not, does the same issue occur if you pair it on one of the other slots?  Either way, Logitech Tech Support would be the recommended route.

Comment: @JW0914 I know I can find workaround for this, but this is not my question. The main purpose of this mouse is that it has multiple channels (no, I didn't change it by accident).
But still, I really want this to work with Bluetooth. I don't want to unplug/replug my dongle every time I move from my home desk.

Comment: @xurei The purpose of trying another BT slot on the MX2, seeing if the issue is still there, is to determine if it's a firmware issue on that specific BT slot. Regardless, Logitech Tech Support would be the appropriate channel for this issue.

Comment: @JW0914 I did try the three slots, none are working.